# как остановить проигрыш музыки по клику

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование

Пробовал ставить autoplay и `document.querySelector('audio').pause()` Почему не работает autoplay? Как сделать, чтоб музыка была в autoplay, не на полную громкость и при нажатии на кнопку паузилась?

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('audio').play()
})
```

```html
<button>Play</button>

<audio autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zadvorsky/three.bas/master/examples/_audio/song.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zadvorsky/three.bas/master/examples/_audio/song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Аттрибут `autoplay="true"` или просто `autoplay`.

Comment: Также стоит упомянуть, что некоторые браузеры запрещают автовоспроизведение в некоторых случаях.

Answer (score 1):

`autoplay` должен работать, непонятно... На краний вариант просто автоматом запускайте ваше аудио через метод `play`. А чтобы переключать состояние видео (играет / на паузе), достаточно проверять на паузе ли видео/аудио. Громкость можно менять через `audio.volume` (используйте числа между 1 и 0, примерно так: 0.50, в данном случае это 50% громкости).

```js
let audio = document.querySelector('audio')

audio.volume = 0.75

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {

  audio.paused
    ? audio.play()
    : audio.pause()
})
```

```html
<button>Play</button>

<audio autoplay>
  <source src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zadvorsky/three.bas/master/examples/_audio/song.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zadvorsky/three.bas/master/examples/_audio/song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Вот вариант для автоматического запуска без `autoplay`:

```js
let audio = document.querySelector('audio')

audio.play() // Просто сразу запускаем аудио вне события клика.

// audio.autoplay = true // Но если сильно хочется то автоплей можно применить и так

audio.volume = 0.75

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {

  audio.paused
    ? audio.play()
    : audio.pause()
})
```

```html
<button>Play</button>

<audio>
  <source src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zadvorsky/three.bas/master/examples/_audio/song.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zadvorsky/three.bas/master/examples/_audio/song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Дело вкуса, но описание самого переключения я бы предпочел сделать так: `audio[audio.paused ? 'play' : 'pause']();`. К тому же анализаторы кода, типа JSLint или JSHint, более благосклонные именно к такому синтаксису, особенно если они интегрированны в вашу IDE,

Comment: @NNL993 Autoplay все равно почему-то не работет. А через метод play это как? Попробовал к querySelector добавить метод плей, пробовал вынести просто audio.play(). Не выходит

Comment: @nonniks странно, ведь вроде у вас метод плей просто работает... У вас какой браузер вообще (Название, версия)?

Comment: к тому же в настройках браузера может быть запрещено автопроигрывание

Comment: проигрывание должно инициироваться пользователем

Comment: Большое спасибо за интересный синтаксис `audio[audio.paused ? 'play' : 'pause']()` Много я делал плеяков, но этого не знал. ` :-) `

Answer (score 0):

Уже не один год разработчики браузеров делают всё для того, чтобы **autoplay** не работал до тех пор, пока пользователь хоть что-то не сделает на странице. Уже очень много об этом говорилось и на мой взгляд самая эффективную замену **autoplay** можно сделать так:

```
document.onpointerover =_=> audio.play();
```

Т. е., человек после обновления страницы заводит курсор на страницу и в этот момент начинает звучать музыка, и при этом кажется, что она идёт автоматом.

Ещё альтернативный вариант запускать музыку во время прокрутки, но мне кажется, что первый вариант лучше.